# How to parse websocket data frames

Tags: php, websocket

I get some PHP code, but I don't understand why it's written this way. Can somebody please explain it to me?

```
function unmask($text)
{
    $length = ord($text[1]) & 127;
    if ($length == 126) {
        $masks = substr($text, 4, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 8);
    } elseif ($length == 127) {
        $masks = substr($text, 10, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 14);
    } else {
        $masks = substr($text, 2, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 6);
    }
    $text = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i % 4];
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Specifically, what does:

```
$length = ord($text[1]) & 127
```

...mean, exactly?

Comment: ord ist just converting the value of the first char of a string to a number between 0 - 255 (Ascii-Codes) - the & is as far as I know used for pointers and "Bits that are set in both $a and $b are set." (Bit-Operator) - however, it makes no difference in my small test (echo (ord("a") & 127).